# Linenumbers in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, line-numbering

I have to add line numbers to a document. It would be nice if the line numbers are also printed (and counted) inside tables. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{longtable}{|p{\textwidth}|}
  \blindtext 
\end{longtable}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\textwidth}|}
  \blindtext 
\end{tabular}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Giving the following result:

[image: no linenumbers next to table]

The `\longtable` doesn't get numbers at all, the regular `\tabular` is considered a single line. There seems to be a `longtable` option to the `lineno` package, but this also adds just one line number to the whole table.

How do I get line numbers for each line in a longtable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\internallinenumbers` seems to work.

Update: Comment asked to change the spacing inside the new env. To use `\internallinenumbers` it needs a new env. One can use `minipage` or `parbox` and may be others, and it will work. To adjust the margins, here is the updated example using `\vspace{5pt}` but there are other ways to adjust margins and spacings one can use.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{20pt}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.7\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|}\hline
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
\vspace{5pt}
\internallinenumbers
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
&
This is a test

This is a test
\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\blindtext

\nolinenumbers
\begin{tabular}{|p{\textwidth}|}
\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{
\vspace{5pt}
\internallinenumbers
  \blindtext
}
\end{tabular}
\linenumbers
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't have LaTeX at hand right now, are the minipages necessary?

Comment: @Jasper yes. Without it, it will not work.

Comment: Why is the L sticking out of the table border in line 10 (or how do you fix it)?

Comment: @Jasper you can fine tune the layout in number of way. I used `vspace`, but there could be other and better ways. Updated example.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is way too ugly (speaking about the source code) for my purposes (many cells with 2 or 3 lines). I guess I'll go without line numbers then.